# Upgraded the VMWare and now I can not run a guess machine

Tags: kubuntu, vmware

Today I upgraded my VMWare using the dialog window at its startup suggesting that since there's a new version I should upgrade. Doing that, now I cannot start any virtual machine. I face the error:

```
Could not open /dev/vmmon: No such file or directory.
Please make sure that the kernel module `vmmon' is loaded.
```

Searching online for the possible solutions, I found this:

```
sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

Running the above command results in:

```
[AppLoader] GLib does not have GSettings support.
Stopping VMware services:
   VMware Authentication Daemon                                        done
   VM communication interface socket family                            done
   Virtual machine communication interface                             done
   Virtual machine monitor                                             done
   Blocking file system                                                done
make: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only'
Using kernel build system.
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-33-generic/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-33-generic'
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/linux/driver.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/linux/driverLog.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/common/memtrack.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/common/apic.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/common/hashFunc.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/common/cpuid.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/common/task.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/common/comport.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/common/phystrack.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/vmcore/moduleloop.o
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.h:32:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.c:43:
/tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/./include/x86msr.h:129:0: warning: "MSR_MISC_FEATURES_ENABLES" redefined
 #define MSR_MISC_FEATURES_ENABLES            0x140

In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/nospec-branch.h:9:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/paravirt.h:10,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/irqflags.h:65,
                 from ./include/linux/irqflags.h:16,
                 from ./include/linux/rcupdate.h:39,
                 from ./include/linux/rculist.h:11,
                 from ./include/linux/pid.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/sched.h:14,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.c:31:
./arch/x86/include/asm/msr-index.h:606:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define MSR_MISC_FEATURES_ENABLES 0x00000140

In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:5:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h:5,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:53,
                 from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:38,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:7,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:81,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:51,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/mmu.h:5,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/desc.h:7,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/common/task.c:70:
./arch/x86/include/asm/processor-flags.h:39:0: warning: "CR3_PCID_MASK" redefined
 #define CR3_PCID_MASK 0xFFFull

In file included from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm_x86.h:41:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm_x86_64.h:40,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm.h:46,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/common/task.c:53:
/tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/./include/x86_basic_defs.h:78:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define CR3_PCID_MASK  0xFFF

In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/nospec-branch.h:9:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/paravirt_types.h:46,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/ptrace.h:92,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/math_emu.h:5,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:12,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h:5,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:53,
                 from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:38,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:7,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:81,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:51,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/mmu.h:5,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/desc.h:7,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/common/task.c:70:
./arch/x86/include/asm/msr-index.h:606:0: warning: "MSR_MISC_FEATURES_ENABLES" redefined
 #define MSR_MISC_FEATURES_ENABLES 0x00000140

In file included from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.h:32:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/common/task.c:51:
/tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/./include/x86msr.h:129:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define MSR_MISC_FEATURES_ENABLES            0x140

In file included from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm_x86.h:41:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm_x86_64.h:40,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm.h:46,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.c:46:
/tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/./include/x86_basic_defs.h:78:0: warning: "CR3_PCID_MASK" redefined
 #define CR3_PCID_MASK  0xFFF

In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/irqflags.h:5:0,
                 from ./include/linux/irqflags.h:16,
                 from ./include/linux/rcupdate.h:39,
                 from ./include/linux/rculist.h:11,
                 from ./include/linux/pid.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/sched.h:14,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.c:31:
./arch/x86/include/asm/processor-flags.h:39:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define CR3_PCID_MASK 0xFFFull

/tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/common/phystrack.o: warning: objtool: PhysTrack_Free() falls through to next function PhysTrack_Add()
/tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/common/phystrack.o: warning: objtool: PhysTrack_Add() falls through to next function PhysTrack_Remove()
/tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/common/phystrack.o: warning: objtool: PhysTrack_Remove() falls through to next function PhysTrack_Test()
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/bootstrap/monLoaderVmmon.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/bootstrap/monLoader.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/bootstrap/bootstrap.o
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/./common/vmx86.h:32:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/vmcore/moduleloop.c:35:
/tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/./include/x86msr.h:129:0: warning: "MSR_MISC_FEATURES_ENABLES" redefined
 #define MSR_MISC_FEATURES_ENABLES            0x140

In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/nospec-branch.h:9:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/paravirt.h:10,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/irqflags.h:65,
                 from ./include/linux/irqflags.h:16,
                 from ./include/linux/rcupdate.h:39,
                 from ./include/linux/rculist.h:11,
                 from ./include/linux/pid.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/sched.h:14,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/vmcore/moduleloop.c:31:
./arch/x86/include/asm/msr-index.h:606:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define MSR_MISC_FEATURES_ENABLES 0x00000140

In file included from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm.h:43:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:60:
/tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/./include/x86msr.h:129:0: warning: "MSR_MISC_FEATURES_ENABLES" redefined
 #define MSR_MISC_FEATURES_ENABLES            0x140

In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/nospec-branch.h:9:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/paravirt.h:10,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/irqflags.h:65,
                 from ./include/linux/irqflags.h:16,
                 from ./include/linux/rcupdate.h:39,
                 from ./include/linux/rculist.h:11,
                 from ./include/linux/pid.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/sched.h:14,
                 from ./include/linux/binfmts.h:5,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:32:
./arch/x86/include/asm/msr-index.h:606:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define MSR_MISC_FEATURES_ENABLES 0x00000140

/tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/bootstrap/monLoaderVmmon.o: warning: objtool: MonLoaderCallout_AllocMPN() falls through to next function MonLoaderCallout_MapMPNInPTE()
/tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/bootstrap/monLoaderVmmon.o: warning: objtool: MonLoaderCallout_FillPage() falls through to next function MonLoaderCallout_CopyFromBlob()
/tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/bootstrap/monLoaderVmmon.o: warning: objtool: MonLoaderCallout_CopyFromBlob() falls through to next function MonLoaderCallout_GetSharedUserPage()
/tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/bootstrap/monLoaderVmmon.o: warning: objtool: MonLoaderCallout_GetSharedHostPage() falls through to next function MonLoaderCallout_IsPrivileged()
/tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/bootstrap/monLoaderVmmon.o: warning: objtool: .text: unexpected end of section
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm_x86.h:41:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm_x86_64.h:40,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm.h:46,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:60:
/tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/./include/x86_basic_defs.h:78:0: warning: "CR3_PCID_MASK" redefined
 #define CR3_PCID_MASK  0xFFF

In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/irqflags.h:5:0,
                 from ./include/linux/irqflags.h:16,
                 from ./include/linux/rcupdate.h:39,
                 from ./include/linux/rculist.h:11,
                 from ./include/linux/pid.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/sched.h:14,
                 from ./include/linux/binfmts.h:5,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:32:
./arch/x86/include/asm/processor-flags.h:39:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define CR3_PCID_MASK 0xFFFull

In file included from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/./common/vmx86.h:32:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/linux/driver.h:32,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:47:
/tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/./include/x86msr.h:129:0: warning: "MSR_MISC_FEATURES_ENABLES" redefined
 #define MSR_MISC_FEATURES_ENABLES            0x140

In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/nospec-branch.h:9:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/paravirt_types.h:46,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/ptrace.h:92,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/math_emu.h:5,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:12,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h:5,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:53,
                 from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:38,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:7,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:81,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:51,
                 from ./include/linux/wait.h:9,
                 from ./include/linux/wait_bit.h:8,
                 from ./include/linux/fs.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/highmem.h:5,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:25:
./arch/x86/include/asm/msr-index.h:606:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define MSR_MISC_FEATURES_ENABLES 0x00000140

In file included from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm_x86.h:41:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm_x86_64.h:40,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm.h:46,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:49:
/tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/./include/x86_basic_defs.h:78:0: warning: "CR3_PCID_MASK" redefined
 #define CR3_PCID_MASK  0xFFF

In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:5:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h:5,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:53,
                 from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:38,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:7,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:81,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:51,
                 from ./include/linux/wait.h:9,
                 from ./include/linux/wait_bit.h:8,
                 from ./include/linux/fs.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/highmem.h:5,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:25:
./arch/x86/include/asm/processor-flags.h:39:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define CR3_PCID_MASK 0xFFFull

/tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:985:1: warning: always_inline function might not be inlinable [-Wattributes]
 LinuxDriverSyncReadTSCs(uint64 *delta) // OUT: TSC max - TSC min
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.o: warning: objtool: Vmx86EnableHVOnCPU() falls through to next function Vmx86GetMSR()
/tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/common/task.o: warning: objtool: Task_Switch()+0x44e: indirect call found in RETPOLINE build
/tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/common/task.o: warning: objtool: .text: unexpected end of section
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/vmmon.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/vmmon.mod.o
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only/vmmon.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-33-generic'
/usr/bin/make -C $PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= postbuild
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only'
make[1]: 'postbuild' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only'
cp -f vmmon.ko ./../vmmon.o
make: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmmon-only'
make: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmnet-only'
Using kernel build system.
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-33-generic/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-33-generic'
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmnet-only/driver.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmnet-only/hub.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmnet-only/userif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmnet-only/netif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmnet-only/bridge.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmnet-only/procfs.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmnet-only/smac_compat.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmnet-only/smac.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmnet-only/vnetEvent.o
In file included from ./include/linux/pci.h:37:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmnet-only/compat_netdevice.h:27,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmnet-only/netif.c:43:
./include/linux/pci_ids.h:2261:0: warning: "PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE" redefined
 #define PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE  0x15ad

In file included from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmnet-only/net.h:38:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:26,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmnet-only/netif.c:42:
/tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmnet-only/vm_device_version.h:56:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE                    0x15AD

In file included from ./include/linux/pci.h:37:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmnet-only/compat_netdevice.h:27,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmnet-only/netif.c:43:
./include/linux/pci_ids.h:2262:0: warning: "PCI_DEVICE_ID_VMWARE_VMXNET3" redefined
 #define PCI_DEVICE_ID_VMWARE_VMXNET3 0x07b0

In file included from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmnet-only/net.h:38:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:26,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmnet-only/netif.c:42:
/tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmnet-only/vm_device_version.h:73:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define PCI_DEVICE_ID_VMWARE_VMXNET3            0x07B0

  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmnet-only/vnetUserListener.o
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmnet-only/net.h:38:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:26,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmnet-only/bridge.c:53:
/tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmnet-only/vm_device_version.h:56:0: warning: "PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE" redefined
 #define PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE                    0x15AD

In file included from ./include/linux/pci.h:37:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmnet-only/compat_netdevice.h:27,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmnet-only/bridge.c:52:
./include/linux/pci_ids.h:2261:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE  0x15ad

In file included from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmnet-only/net.h:38:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:26,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmnet-only/bridge.c:53:
/tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmnet-only/vm_device_version.h:73:0: warning: "PCI_DEVICE_ID_VMWARE_VMXNET3" redefined
 #define PCI_DEVICE_ID_VMWARE_VMXNET3            0x07B0

In file included from ./include/linux/pci.h:37:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmnet-only/compat_netdevice.h:27,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmnet-only/bridge.c:52:
./include/linux/pci_ids.h:2262:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define PCI_DEVICE_ID_VMWARE_VMXNET3 0x07b0

  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmnet-only/vmnet.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmnet-only/vmnet.mod.o
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmnet-only/vmnet.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-33-generic'
/usr/bin/make -C $PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= postbuild
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmnet-only'
make[1]: 'postbuild' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmnet-only'
cp -f vmnet.ko ./../vmnet.o
make: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-pLicGV/vmnet-only'
Starting VMware services:
   Virtual machine monitor                                            failed
   Virtual machine communication interface                             done
   VM communication interface socket family                            done
   Blocking file system                                                done
   Virtual ethernet                                                   failed
   VMware Authentication Daemon                                        done
Unable to start services
```

I'm using **Kubuntu 18.04** with **kernel version 4.15.0-33-generic**.

**[UPDATE]**

```
$ lsmod | grep vmmon
$ sudo modprobe vmmon
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'vmmon': Required key not available
```

Comment: What does `lsmod | grep vmmon` show? Did try you try to reboot? Does `modprobe vmmon` work after a reboot?

Comment: @TomášPospíšek Updated

Comment: Google for that error and see whether the suggested solutions help you. You did reboot, right?

Comment: Goolging the last error, I `sudo mokutil --disable-validation`ed and it fixed my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP was able to work around the problem via `sudo mokutil --disable-validation`